# Imagekit as a foreignkey - adding an image in admin

Tags: django, imagekit, django-imagekit

This relates to adding information in a Foreignkey field in the main admin screen.

I have a Staff model. I need mugshots in 3 formats. I'd like to use `django-imagekit` for processing.

I've made a Photo model to store the mugshot, and added it as a Foreignkey to `Staff` as `photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)`.

Question: How can I add the mugshot directly in the `Staff` admin screen, i.e. avoid having to upload the mugshots separately in their own admin screen then  link to them from `Staff`?

Thank you for your thoughts ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what screen you need it in, but I guess you need it in the details/edit screen?
The most simple method is creating a template in your app, called:

/templates/admin//staff/change_form.html

In this template place the following:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if not add and original.photo %}
<img src="{{original.photo.url}}" alt="Photo" />
{% endif %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

This places the image above the rest of the content if in edit modus (so no image in add mode).

If you need it in the list you can add a custom function to your admin.py as well returning the HTML snippet for showing the photo.